# Expected value of $\min(x, c)$, where $c$ is constant??

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assuming that $x$ follows a distribution with pdf $f$ and cdf $F$, the expected value of $x$ is

$$E[x] = \int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} x f(x)dx$$

Assuming now that I have a variable $y = \min(x, c)$, where $c$ is a constant, what  is the expected value of $y$?

My guess is that it would be

$$E[y] = \left(\int_{-\infty}^c x f(x)dx \right) + c \left(1 - F(x) \right)$$

but I can't prove it. Is my assumption correct, and how do I get the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are **almost** right.

Consider that:
$$y = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if}~x<c \\
c & \text{if}~x\geq c
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore:

$$\mathbb{E}[y] = \int_{-\infty}^c x f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{+\infty} c f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^c x f(x) dx  + c (1 - F(c)),$$

since

$$\int_{c}^{+\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^{c} f(x) dx = 1 - F(c).$$

Comment: thanks. That's what I though, but still fail to see what $f(y)$ would be, to get that result

Comment: In this case $f(y)$ is the sum of a continuous pdf for $y \in (-\infty, c)$ plus a Dirac delta in $y=c$. But I think that this is a new question that you should ask separately. Here you just asked the expected value of $y$, not its pdf.